# DynamoDB Lambda SpringBoot - Data not saving

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Spring Boot and I am trying to build a serverless CRUD. I am using lambda and dynamodb for this. I created a endpoint /api/products : POST to save the Product.

When I call the endpoint I am getting 502 Error.
[image]

My Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.272</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Config File

```
@Configuration
public class ProductConfiguration {
    @Value("${ACCESS_KEY}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${SECRET_KEY}")
    private String secretKey;
    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1) // Change the region as per your setup
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper() {
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB());
    }

}
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepoImpl implements ProductRepo {
    private final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ProductRepoImpl(DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper) {
        this.dynamoDBMapper = dynamoDBMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public String saveProduct(Product p) {
        dynamoDBMapper.save(p);
        return "done";
    }
}
```

When I fire the API I am getting that error, but I cant see any errors in the CloudWatch

[image]